# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute

Tags: python, django

I have 2 different application in python. I want to import model and use it to make serializer function in another app. Here is my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_models
from . import models as client_models
from crm.models import models as crm_models
from rest_framework import serializers



class Capability(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = crm_models.Capability
        fields = ["id", "name"]


class Client(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    industry = Industry(read_only=True)
    capability = Capability(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = client_models.Client
        fields = [
            "id",
            "company",
            "entity",
            "account_status",
            "capability"]
```

Here I am getting error for,

```
in Meta
    model = crm_models.Capability
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Capability'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the file structure I'd take a guess that you want to change your import to:

```
from crm import models as crm_models
```

as I think you are looking for models in models currently.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :-

```
from crm.models import Capability

class Capability(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Capability
        fields = ["id", "name"]
```